# How to choose between Hibernate and JDBC?

Tags: hibernate, orm, jdbc

I have to develop a Java EE project. I am confused after reading different tutorials on JDBC and Hibernate.

After reading those tutorials, I found out both have some pros and cons. Now the problem is how I can decide which one is best? Additionally I'd like to know for which type of project in general I would use JDBC and for which type of project I would use Hibernate.

Using a test application where I have 100.000 records in a single table, I noticed that when using JDBC I can fetch all records in 3 to 4 seconds. When I used Hibernate it took 12 to 14 seconds.

Why is Hibernate's performance so much worse, and how can I increase the performance of Hibernate to be near that of JDBC?

Comment: IMO It all depends on project / application, If your following DDD (domain driven design) then hibernate will suit you more and you can utilise it in best possible way, on the other hand if your application is a kind of batch app (or you have db design ready at hand) then pure jdbc is better than hibernate or any other ORM

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in hibernate though i am just pointing out few points why i prefer hibernate over simple jdbc on my experience.

I have used hibernate with JPA annotations in a maven project

1. You can create all your model and define relationships using annotations.Then running one maven command created the entire relational database,tables and relation based on my models.Well that saves a lot of time
2. Hibernate will convert the result set into your models in the background based on your getters and setters.Unlike jdbc you will not have to extract the result set by yourself into models.Again you saved a lot of time
3. Hibernate usually fetches all your relational objects eagerly.So you don't have to bother writing join queries.(You can always specify whether you want to eager fetch/lazy fetch)

4.There are methods for save,update,delete where you can pass the model instance as argument

So if you are set out to write a Java EE project which is going to grow over the time and you want to save some time from writing extra classes you can go for Hibernate.All of this are from my small experience.But there is a lot more you can do in hibernate.Please refer the hibernate docs

Answer (score 0):

Well Irrespective what type of project you are into, Hibernate will always make your life easier. This brings database operations closer to your domain model. You query database using the convention of java classes, just how you would access fields in java same why you can specify fields in your query (rather than typing in the SQL and everytime you type a query you need to cross check which field is mapped by which column name). Also, hibernate will return you the domain objects after hitting database query and that is always helpful if you look at JDBC where you have to construct all this stuff by yourself.

Over all if you working in a relativly small project you can get away using JDBC as well but when in mid-to-large size projects it is always helpful to use some ORM solution not necessarly Hibernate.

Comment: using a test application when i have one lakh reords in a sigle table.i notice using JDBC i fetceh all reords in 3 seconds.And when i used Hibernate it takes 12 to 14 seconds.Then how hibernate is batter./???

Answer (score 0):

It is not an "either or" situation. There are lots of interesting [ORM solutions](http://sourceforge.net/search/?q=&fq%5B%5D=trove:45&fq%5B%5D=trove:809&fq%5B%5D=trove:198) in addition to Hibernate. I would be less concerned about performance unless you have a particularly db-intensive algorithm. You should consider learning curve and source code maintainability. My ORM library strives for simple learning curve and minimal programming: [sormula](http://www.sormula.org)